# system() API getting stuck occasionally

Tags: c, while-loop, system, gettimeofday

I have a code where I am running the system API to check the pid of another process in a while(1) loop. There is a sleep of 1 sec in the loop. Also I am checking if the call is getting executed every second or not in this way,

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<signal.h>

int main()
{
    struct timespec now;
    unsigned long long prev;
    int diff = 0;
    if( clock_gettime( CLOCK_REALTIME, &now) == -1 ) {
            perror( "clock gettime" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
    prev = now.tv_sec;
    while(1) {
        int ret =  system("/sbin/pidof vim > /dev/null");
        if( clock_gettime( CLOCK_REALTIME, &now) == -1 ) {
            perror( "clock gettime" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }
        if(prev != 0 ) {
            diff = abs(now.tv_sec - prev);
            if( diff > 1)
                printf("Diff %d prev = %lu now = %lu\n",diff,prev,now.tv_sec);
        }
        prev = now.tv_sec;
        sleep(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Ideally I expect the print should not be seen at all , but many times I am seeing a diff of 2 seconds. If I comment the system() API, then I dont see the print.I even ran a strace with timing option and dont see any increase in timing when the issue is seen.

Are there any known issues where system() gets stuck for a while?

Sample output

```
Diff 2 prev = 1640101799 now = 1640101801
Diff 2 prev = 1640101911 now = 1640101913
```

Comment: I think you're just running into roundoff error of the clock.

Comment: The net time between successive calls to `system` is always going to be a little more than 1 second.  Suppose it takes, on average, 0.1 second to do the `system()` call.  So if you happen to call it once at 12:34:56.95, the next one will be at 12:34:58.05, and since you're only looking at `now.tv_sec`, it will look like 2 seconds went by.

Comment: `if( diff > 1)` so diff was equal or less than 1.

Comment: The first call might be at `1640101799.999` while the second is at `1640101801.001`. The time difference is only `1.002` seconds, but since the times round down it looks like 2 seconds.

Comment: You should use functions that have more than 1 second of precision.

Comment: Now, with all of this said, using `system()` to "shell out" to another command is always going to be faintly if not actually unreliable.  You should be prepared for it to fail, once in a while, in ways that are both more surprising and more frequent than ordinary library function calls.

Comment: @SteveSummit I forgot to wind my computer.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the replies. I will check with usec instead of sec as it looks to be a round off issue.

Comment: @Sekhar Don't look at `tv_nsec` *instead of* `tv_sec` — you'll have a different set of problems that way.  You want to look at `tv_sec` *and* `tv_nsec`.

Comment: @SteveSummit Thanks. will look at what you suggested.